# Wrong Get Text Keyword - Robot Framework with SIkuli Lib

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, sikuli

Good Morning!

I have a little problem. Could anyone help?

I'm using Sikuli with Robot Framework.

I have an image saved and I would like to query the same image in the system to obtain and validate if it is successful.
For that, I'm using the keyword Get Text.

However, when I use the Log, it returns the text of the saved image and not the text of the system screen.
But if you access the Robot log, the system image text appears.

What am I doing wrong?

**Get Text line:**

```
${X}    Get Text    aba_redescontos_pendentes_pagamento.png
```

> The image contain the text "Pendentes de Pagamento (1)."
>
> The real image in system is "Pendentes de Pagamento (0)."

When i call the Log, i received the text "Pendentes de Pagamento (1)".

Why??
I had to get the text "Pendentes de Pagamento (0)".

my robot log print

[image]

Waiting!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Screen has the string with (1) too somewhere and your reference image matches that location ?

Comment: No, Rasjani.
It's something unique on the screen... =/

I added the screenshot above in the description.
From the screen, I do a Get Text with my image from the "Pendentes Pagamento..." tab.  Can you help me?!